# Android not reading XML file from another webhosting

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-activity

I have this simple problem the problem is that i have this XML file  myText.XML on this link

http://alsauditech.com/FinalFetch/myText.xml 
everything is fine when i read this file from this web server

but when i try to read the myText.xml file from this server 
http://www.islamicessentials.org/audio/myText.xml(www.ixwebhosting.com/
)

my application CRASHES i tried everything even gave permission 777 and also filed a suppport ticket and also tried to chat but they are always busy

my logcat

```
06-27 14:00:59.689: I/Process(23648): Sending signal. PID: 23648 SIG: 9
06-27 14:01:04.741: I/webkit/webview(23718): WebView() constructor=android.webkit.WebView@40531360
06-27 14:01:04.822: I/webkit/webview(23718): Webview.loadUrl() this=android.webkit.WebView@40531360url: data:text/html;UTF-8,<html><body><h1>Live Broadcast</h1><br><object data='http://23.226.131.127/player.php' width='330' height='50' type='text/html'></object><br><object data='http://23.226.131.127/stats_bb_ios_g.php' width='330' height='100' type='text/html'></object> </body></html>
06-27 14:01:04.857: I/InetAddress(23718): InetAddress_getaddrinfo>
06-27 14:01:04.857: I/InetAddress(23718): InetAddress_getaddrinfo<
06-27 14:01:04.864: I/System.out(23718): [socket][0] connection /71.18.205.253:80;LocalPort=56453(0)
06-27 14:01:04.865: I/System.out(23718): /71.18.205.253:80(0)
06-27 14:01:04.865: I/OSNetworkSystem(23718): OSNetworkSystem_connect fd=-1; timeout = 60000
06-27 14:01:04.887: I/System.out(23718): /23.226.131.127:80(0)
06-27 14:01:04.888: I/OSNetworkSystem(23718): OSNetworkSystem_connect fd=-1; timeout = 60000
06-27 14:01:04.892: I/System.out(23718): /23.226.131.127:80(0)
06-27 14:01:04.893: I/OSNetworkSystem(23718): OSNetworkSystem_connect fd=-1; timeout = 60000
06-27 14:01:05.117: I/System.out(23718): Socket[addr=/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=56453]
06-27 14:01:05.117: I/System.out(23718): [socket][/192.168.1.3:56453]
06-27 14:01:05.117: I/System.out(23718): setSoSndTimeout:0
06-27 14:01:05.118: I/System.out(23718): setSendBufferSize:8096
06-27 14:01:05.120: I/System.out(23718): doReceiveResponse
06-27 14:01:05.177: I/System.out(23718): Socket[addr=/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=35199]
06-27 14:01:05.177: I/System.out(23718): setSendBufferSize:8192
06-27 14:01:05.447: I/InetAddress(23718): InetAddress_getaddrinfo>
06-27 14:01:05.447: I/InetAddress(23718): InetAddress_getaddrinfo<
06-27 14:01:05.448: I/System.out(23718): [socket][1] connection /71.18.205.253:80;LocalPort=50036(0)
06-27 14:01:05.448: I/System.out(23718): /71.18.205.253:80(0)
06-27 14:01:05.448: I/OSNetworkSystem(23718): OSNetworkSystem_connect fd=-1; timeout = 60000
06-27 14:01:06.104: E/MediaPlayer(23718): error (1, -1004)
06-27 14:01:06.105: E/MediaPlayer(23718): Error (1,-1004)
06-27 14:01:08.190: I/System.out(23718): Socket[addr=/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=37596]
06-27 14:01:08.190: I/System.out(23718): setSendBufferSize:8192
06-27 14:01:08.707: I/System.out(23718): Socket[addr=/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=50036]
06-27 14:01:08.708: I/System.out(23718): [socket][/192.168.1.3:50036]
06-27 14:01:08.708: I/System.out(23718): setSoSndTimeout:0
06-27 14:01:08.708: I/System.out(23718): setSendBufferSize:8096
06-27 14:01:08.709: I/System.out(23718): doReceiveResponse
06-27 14:01:08.710: E/dalvikvm(23718): [DVM] mmap return base = 45d99000
06-27 14:01:09.077: E/Error:(23718): expected: /meta read: head (position:END_TAG </head>@16:10 in java.io.StringReader@40542110) 
06-27 14:01:09.080: W/dalvikvm(23718): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e6a8)
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.expandablelistview/islamicessentials.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1741)
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1760)
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:156)
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1000)
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718):    at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3827)
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:969)
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:727)
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718):    at islamicessentials.StreamManager.AudioManaer(StreamManager.java:104)
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718):    at islamicessentials.MainActivity.prepareListData(MainActivity.java:127)
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718):    at islamicessentials.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1705)
06-27 14:01:09.084: E/AndroidRuntime(23718):    ... 11 more
06-27 14:01:11.511: I/System.out(23718): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:35199]
06-27 14:01:15.512: I/System.out(23718): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:37596]
06-27 14:01:38.504: I/System.out(23718): /23.226.131.127:80(0)
06-27 14:01:38.505: I/OSNetworkSystem(23718): OSNetworkSystem_connect fd=-1; timeout = 60000
06-27 14:01:38.794: I/System.out(23718): Socket[addr=/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=51337]
06-27 14:01:38.794: I/System.out(23718): setSendBufferSize:8192
06-27 14:01:45.110: I/System.out(23718): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:51337]
```

Thanks in Advance From
Muhammad Zeeshan

```
AudioManager Function

public List<String> AudioManaer(int ArrayPosition)
{


/*if(ArrayPosition == 0)
{

    URL = "http://islamicessentials.org/audio/myText.xml";
}else if(ArrayPosition == 1)
{
    URL = "http://islamicessentials.org/audio/myText.xml";
}else if(ArrayPosition == 2)
{
    URL = "http://islamicessentials.org/audio/myText.xml";
}*/
URL = "http://www.islamicessentials.org/audio/myText.xml";

//The PHP script that creates all the files
String ndp = "http://islamicessentials.org/audio/index.php";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

try {
  client.execute(new HttpGet(ndp));
} catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Something is just not right so i have closed the application");
    System.exit(0);
} 


List<String> TestList = new ArrayList<String>();

String xml = this.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
Document doc = this.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
```

NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);//Line 104

```
// looping through all item nodes <item>3
MyArray = new String[2][nl.getLength()];
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    // creating new HashMap
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
String id = map.put(KEY_ID, this.getValue(e, KEY_ID).toString());
String name =   map.put(KEY_NAME, this.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
String cost =  map.put(KEY_COST, this.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
String desc =   map.put(KEY_DESC, this.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

    // adding HashList to ArrayLis


for (String key: map.keySet()) {

   // System.out.println("key : " + key);
    System.out.println("value : " + map.get("url"));
    MyArray[0][i] = map.get("url");

}

TestList.add(map.get("name"));

 //   TestList.add(map.get("url"));


            //map.get("url");

}

    return TestList;    
}
```

prepareListData

```
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Recent Audios");
    listDataHeader.add("English Lectures Of The Month");
    listDataHeader.add("Women's Lectures Of The Month");
    listDataHeader.add("Lectures Of The Month");
    listDataHeader.add("KALAAM-E-MUHABBAT");



    //This is where all the dynamic populating happens
    StreamManager stm = new StreamManager();
```

listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), stm.AudioManaer(0)); // Line 127

```
   listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), stm.AudioManaer(1));
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), stm.AudioManaer(2));
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), stm.AudioManaer(2));
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), stm.AudioManaer(2));

                for(int i=0;i<StreamManager.MyArray[0].length;i++)
                 {
         System.out.println("All Urls Are Coming"+StreamManager.MyArray[0][i]);     
                 }
}
```

UPDATED :

i have found the problem is that is not able no read it as an XML file on the other server

The ERROR message

```
01-01 08:07:01.408: E/Error:(1503): expected: /meta read: head (position:END_TAG </head>@16:10 in java.io.StringReader@405d1c08)
```

Comment: _and also filed a suppport ticket and also tried to chat but they are always busy_ Change hosting provider, man.

Comment: @BackSlash Please just tell me the solution i you have

Comment: can you add the code for `AudioManaer` and your main activity (onCreate and `prepareListData`)

Comment: Start with solving the `NullPointerException`. Whats on line 104 of StreamManager and line 127 of MainActivity?

Comment: @hypd09 i have posted

Comment: @greenapps i have posted my fucntions

Comment: Don't know why you address me as i asked for something different.

Comment: @greenapps can you check i have dont some edits
i have added line 127 and 104

Comment: You know what you have to do now: find out if `doc` and/or something on line 127 is null. And further i doubt if you indicated the right line for 127 as it should be a call to 104.

Comment: @greenapps  i have checked everything there is no error when i use the other link

Comment: It is indeed strange that from another server yoy cannot grab your file. Do not say 'i checked all' as we will not know what you did exactly. Is `xml` null? Did you start checking that? Show how you check please. Add it here to your code.

Comment: With what? I see no checks for null.

Comment: @greenapps this is where it throws
01-01 08:07:01.408: E/Error:(1503): expected: /meta read: head (position:END_TAG </head>@16:10 in java.io.StringReader@405d1c08)

Comment: Nonsense. You have a null pointer exception. Try to find out where. You did not add the checks i proposed. Why should i spend more time here?